# how to set up hierarchy foreach loop for treeview nodes childer

Tags: c#, treeview

I have program which add and remove unwanted chapter from tree view. Everything I am writing to file, which later is generated to PDF. First of all, here is my code of files writing:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            { 
            var header = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\dir\header.tex");
            var footer = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\dir\footer.tex");
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine(header);

            foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
            {

                var tag = node.Tag as string;
                sb.AppendLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) ? node.Text : tag);

            }

            sb.AppendLine(footer);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C: \dir\final.tex", sb.ToString());
        }
            { 
            var chapaheader = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\dir\chapaheader.tex");
            var sba = new StringBuilder();
            sba.AppendLine(chapaheader);
                foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
                {
                    foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
                    {

                        var tag = child.Tag as string;
                        sba.AppendLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) ? child.Text : tag);
                    }
                    File.WriteAllText(@"C: \dir\chapterA.tex", sba.ToString());
                }
```

I have about 5chapter and I dont know how to write each chapters sections in right chapters file. For now my program is doing great by adding right chapters to main file, but chapters A file is full of others chapter sections and chapters B,C,D,E is empty. So I think I need to make it hierarchic foreach loop. Maybe some could help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code , `recursive method`

```
IEnumerable<TreeNode> Iterate(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach(TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        yield return node;

        foreach (var child in Iterate(node.Nodes)
        {
           yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```